# Переход на другой диск cmd (Windows 7)

Tags: cmd

Как перейти на другой диск в командной строке (cmd)???

Имя диска "b"

Делаю так, но не работает (пробовал вводить во всех регистрах в разных комбинациях)

```
cd /B b:\
```

Comment: а почему `/B`?.

Answer (score 57):

Для случая если требуется просто перейти в корень другого диска, просто укажите имя диска без команды cd

```
b:
```

Далее можно переходить по папкам с помощью команды `cd`.

Можно сразу сменить диск и перейти в папки (см. ответ Bald)

Comment: @Bald Да кто против. Что знал, то и написал. Сейчас буду знать чуть больше.

Answer (score 23):

Для перехода на другой диск в командной строке *Windows* просто укажите его имя с двоеточием. Например, чтобы перейти на диск ***D***, нужно ввести

```
d:
```

Команда `cd` имеет одну особенность. Если в ней указать не тот диск, который сейчас активен, то перехода в нужный каталог не произойдёт. Вы останетесь на активном диске, не перейдя на другой. Чтобы не только сменить текущий каталог на другом диске, но и перейти на него, нужно добавить ключ `/d`:

```
cd /d d:\Folder
```

Answer (score 12):

`D:\>cd /?`

> Вывод имени либо смена текущего каталога.
>
> CHDIR [/D] [диск:][путь] CHDIR [..] CD [/D] [диск:][путь] CD [..]
>
> ..  обозначает переход в родительский каталог.
>
> Команда CD диск: отображает имя текущего каталога указанного диска.
>   Команда CD без параметров отображает имена текущих диска и каталога.
>
> Параметр /D используется для одновременной смены текущих диска и
>   каталога.
>
> Изменение команды CHDIR при включении расширенной обработки команд:
>
> Имя текущего каталога в строке вызова преобразуется к тому же регистру
>   символов, что и для существующих имен на диске.  Так, команда CD
>   C:\TEMP на самом деле сделает текущим каталог C:\Temp, если он
>   существует на диске.
>
> Команда CHDIR перестает рассматривать пробелы как разделители, что
>   позволяет перейти в подкаталог, имя которого содержит пробелы, не
>   заключая все имя каталога в кавычки.  Например:
>
> ```
> cd \winnt\profiles\username\programs\start menu
> ```
>
> приводит к тому же результату, что и:
>
> ```
> cd "\winnt\profiles\username\programs\start menu"
> ```
>
> При отключении расширенной обработки команд используется только второй
>   вариант.

Comment: пробую cd /b ....не работает

Comment: где в справке по команде Вы увидели параметр `b`, в вашем случае команда может выглядеть как `cd /d B:\`

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно запустить DOS окно ("Командная строка") тогда
нажмите Windows + r
и в окне введите и выполните команду

```
cmd /K (b: & cd b:\folder)
```

Если DOS окно уже открыто, то введите

```
b: & cd b:\folder
```

где

```
b:
```

это диск который вам нужен

```
\folder
```

путь к нужной папке

```
& [...]
```

command1 & command2 
Используйте для разделения нескольких команд в одной командной строке. Cmd.exe запускает первую команду, а затем вторую команду.

```
&& [...]
```

command1 && command2 
Используйте для запуска команды, следующей за && только если команда, предшествующая символу, успешна. Cmd.exe запускает первую команду, а затем запускает вторую команду только в том случае, если первая команда успешно завершена.

```
|| [...]
```

command1 || command2 
Используйте для запуска команды, следующей за || только если команда, предшествующая || выходит из строя. Cmd.exe запускает первую команду, а затем запускает вторую команду только в том случае, если первая команда не завершилась успешно (получает код ошибки больше нуля).

```
( ) [...]
```

(command1 & command2) 
Использовать для группировки или размещения нескольких команд.

```
; or ,
```

command1 parameter1;parameter2 
Используйте для разделения параметров команды.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас не правильно введён последний символ
Используйте команду:

```
cd /B b:/
```

Comment: Совсем неверный ответ...